# Firefox extension to open JavaScript links in distinct tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox, web, hyperlink

Please recommend a Firefox extension that will force JavaScript links on a user-defined site to open in ***separate*** new tabs.

More detail:

A web site (not public-facing, sorry) loads links via JavaScript.  It loads them in a new tab.  That's all good.  The trouble is that clicking on a second link opens the target in the same tab as the previous link.

For example, site A is in tab 1.  Clicking on a link in site A loads site B in tab 2.  No problem.  But clicking on another link in site A loads site C in tab 2.  Problem!

Please note that each link is unique every time site A is visited.

I don't have any other requirements.  All Firefox extensions are automatically open-source, so that's a given.  No OS or price constraints applicable.

Comment: What is a javascript link exactly? LInks created with The Javascript `String.link()` method or [old-school](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245868/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-methods-of-putting-javascript-code) `<a href="#" onclick="function(){opensomething()}">click me</a>` code? For the latter case, Perhaps try Firefox extension [Open Links in Tab](https://github.com/averissimo/open-links-in-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

This works if the list of links on that "user-defined site" never changes :

Do this once:

- create a new folder, or a subfolder, in your bookmark bar.
- Create a bookmark for each link on the page, and store the bookmark in the newly created folder.

Do this more often:

- Move the mouse over the bookmark folder
- Select "Open All in tabs"

This shows what I mean but the list is kind of arbitrary

[[image: bookmark toolbar in web browser1]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  That's a great idea.  Unfortunately, every page being linked to is unique.  All the same, I appreciate your tip.  I'll also edit my question to include this relevant fact.